# MAGENTO - how to display sub-category products on category page?

Tags: magento

I wont to display category image and products and sub-categories image and products  on the same page, when i set in category  Is Anchor=yes I get all the products grouped and it's not what i am looking,
any idea how to do that ?

i am looking something like this https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/product-display-grouped-by-subcategories-by-customy.html

Thanks!!!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 1):

Yes is_anchor is the solution. Make Sure root category is set with is_anchor YES. Then try to reindex . Hope this blog will helps you. 
http://dltr.org/blog/magento/486/Magento-automatically-assign-product-to-parent-categories

Comment: I want to display like this https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/product-display-grouped-by-subcategories-by-customy.html

Comment: As per your reference it's not possible by default in Magento we need to customize the category section then you need to prepare the layout as per requirement.